# How To Portray Experience In Two Separate Fields?

Tags: linkedin

I work in two separate fields, and have been working in both for the last 8 years.  The second field of mine started as a side interest and it's now grown into a profession.  There is a problem that I've noticed: people in one field tend to doubt my skills in my field because they think I know too much in the other field (and vice versa).

I don't know what's normal for most people, but in the last eight years, I've rarely worked less than 70 hours a week, with some weeks being even more than that.  In addition, in my free time I attend events for both fields.  In the beginning of my career, working two jobs was the only way to "make it" and I've adopted this system permanently now.

Here's the problem I'm having: would it be better to separate each profession from each other on LinkedIn?  I often do my own contracts for field two, since field one is my "day job" but the feedback from some people expressing doubts about my skill in field one because of my skills in field two, make me wonder if separating profiles would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may backfire badly. People who find both profiles (with pictures of the obviously same person - even if you put up different pictures of you) may be even more certain that you have something to hide. If you do set up different profiles (is that even allowed by LinkedIn's terms of service?), I'd at least *prominently* link them so nobody can accuse you of hiding something.

However, it sounds like you will just need to establish your credentials and reputation for both fields separately.

This should only be a problem for people that do research you, after all. My first reaction on meeting someone is not to search him on LinkedIn, find that he is a champion mud wrestler, and subsequently discount his statistical skills. So you wouldn't need to fear people like me.

Comment: Thanks Stephan; it's general push back I get, but I always welcome people like you who get that some can be solid at two skills.